# Как добавить сертификат SSL java

Tags: java, ssl, openssl

Есть два файла с расширением example.key и example.crt , и есть java приложение с использованием класса HttpsURLConnection. Вопрос, что мне c этими двумя файлами сделать что бы мое приложение заработало. 
 Пробовал использовать PKCS12 и явно указывать в keystore не получилось.

```
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    FileInputStream fis =new 
    FileInputStream(".../example.p12");
    ks.load(fis, "qwerty".toCharArray()); // There are other ways to read 
    the password.
    fis.close();


    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    KeyManagerFactory kmf 
    =KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(ks,"qwerty".toCharArray());
    KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();
    sc.init(kms, null, new SecureRandom());
    URL url = new 
    URL("https://...");
    HttpsURLConnection request = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я плюнул на все эти танцы с бубнами и в итоге за 30 минут сделал то, что не мог за пару дней, я использовал curl4j библиотеку в итоге одна строчка заменила тонну кода с java.net.ssl

```
String json = $("-kX POST --cert crt/example.crt --key crt/example.key -H 
'Content-Type: application/json' -d " + dataJSON+ " example.com");
```